# Form field validation causes problems for multi-field validation

Tags: django

I'm writing a register user form where I am implementing some of my own password validation (checking if the password chosen by the user is complex enough).

So far I've only implemented one requirement, that the password needs to be long enough. If the password fails on this requirement, the whole site crashes. Let me explain why. Here's the form:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password']

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']

        if len(password) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('The password needs to be at least 8 characters long'))

        return password

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if not password == confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('The passwords do not match'))
```

and here's the error:

```
 File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/workout/workoutcal/forms.py", line 43, in clean
    password = cleaned_data['password']
KeyError: 'password'
```

When the `clean_password()` method raises the error, it doesn't return the password, which causes it to go missing from the `self.cleaned_data` dictionary. I could think of one way to solve this problem:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
    try:
        password = cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if not password == confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('The passwords do not match'))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

This way, if there is an error, the program will not crash. If the passwords do not match, we will not get an error message for it, but this should be irrelevant since the password chosen by the user is invalid anyway.

My question is, is this the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, `ValidationError` adds an entry to the `password` field errors dict.

You should use `dict.get()` to get value from `cleaned_data` for a safe access to it.

```
password = cleaned_data.get('password')
confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

if password and confirm_password and not password == confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('The passwords do not match'))
```

The validation error will be catched further in code and processed as a form validation error.

Comment: Password is already required by the form. The issue is not if a user doens't supply a password, it's what to do when password is excluded from `cleaned_data` because of an error being raised by its field validator.

Comment: Well, just change the exception message then.

Comment: There's no reason to catch an empty password field. This is already done automatically by the form. This is not the issue.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. However, this will give us another error that has already been raised by `clean_password()`, thus I think the solution is a bit redundant.

Comment: According to the documentation, you should use `cleaned_data.get()` instead of direct access, thus your code wouldn't throw.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean